# unable to create `/etc/skel/.bash_logout.dpkg-new': No such file or directory

Tags: updates, permissions, etc

I can´t install any updates. I tried `apt-get clean`, `apt-get install -f`, `dpkg --configure -a`. Nothing helps. I even tried to create a file or a directory in `/etc/skel` - it cannot be done, even with root. `/etc/skel` is completely empty.
While trying to update, my Update manager shows me this:

```
Package: /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.2-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
Error: unable to create `/etc/skel/.bash_logout.dpkg-new' (while processing `./etc/skel/.bash_logout'): No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've accidentally deleted the directory `/etc/skel`. Check by typing the following command in a terminal:

```
ls -ld /etc/skel
```

If the directory does exist, post the output of this command for further diagnosis.

If the directory doesn't exist, create it:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/skel
```

You should also reinstall the packages that have files in `/etc/skel`. You're going to update `bash` anyway. Check if there are others by running the command `dpkg -S /etc/skel`. If this lists packages other than `base-files` and `bash`, run `apt-get --reinstall install on them, e.g.`apt-get --reinstall install mksh syslogout`.

Comment: When I type ls -ld /etc/skel, I get this: `drwxr-xr-x 0 mokinys mokinys 0 May 13 11:41 /etc/skel`
Also when I try to reinstall the stuff that I got using command `dpkg -S /etc/skel`, (for example sudo apt-get --reinstall install xubuntu-default-settings), I get similar error:
`unable to create /etc/skel/.Xdefaults.dpkg-new' (while processing ./etc/skel/.Xdefaults'): File or Folder doesn't exist`

Comment: @minihydra That's weird. What about `ls -la /etc/skel` ?

Comment: The output is 0.

Comment: @minihydra What happens if you run `sudo touch /etc/skel/foo`? It may be due to a corrupted package: did you try `sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get --reinstall install bash`?

Comment: When I try `sudo apt-get –reinstall install bash`, I get:
`dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/bash_4.2-2ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create „/etc/skel/.bash_logout.dpkg-new“ (while processing „./etc/skel/.bash_logout“): file or folder doesn't exist
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
         update-alternatives: using /usr/share/man/man7/bash-builtins.7.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man7/builtins.7.gz (builtins.7.gz) in auto mode.`
`sudo touch /etc/skel/foo` doesn't work: file or folder doesn't exist.

Comment: @minihydra Hmmm, there's really something weird with your `/etc/skel`. What about `ls -ld /etc/skel`? If you do `sudo mv /etc/skel /etc/skel.weird && sudo mkdir -m 755 /etc/skel`, does it work, and does it solve the problem? Does `grep -r skel /etc/apparmor*` return anything?

Comment: I tried everything you said, even with a Live-CD, but even after making new /etc/skel it still works the same. Updates cannot be done, I can't create file in /etc/skel and without Live-CD I can't even remove it. `grep -r skel /etc/apparmor*` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @minihydra Have you activated another security framework beyond Apparmor (e.g. SELinux)? What's the error message if you do `sudo rmdir /etc/skel`? Does `mv /etc/skel /etc/skel.weird` work, and afterwards, can you `rmdir /etc/skel.weird`?

Comment: I don't know what the security framework is, so I guess no. When I do `sudo rmdir /etc/skel` I get: cannot remove, device is busy. The skel.weird disappeared on it's own, I didn't remove it.

Comment: @minihydra Hmmm, this behavior makes no sense. What's the output of `cat /proc/mounts`, just to make sure there's nothing bad there? I recommend doing a memory test (choose “memory test” at the boot prompt, let it run for a few hours (at least one full pass)), then a filesystem check (`fsck -n /dev/sda1`, or wherever `/` is mounted).

Comment: @ Gilles Omg I solved it, thanks to `cat /proc/mounts`! The output is long, I uploaded it to http://pastebin.com/wteymguP 
I found the 22 line suspicious so I checked it with `cat /etc/mtab` and I got the line `/home/mokinys /etc/skel none rw,bind 0 0`. So I figured that somehow the computer mounts /etc/skel directory. I did `sudo umount /etc/skel` and tried to update my PC, and it worked!

Comment: btw how to mark this question solved? It was my first question here ever.